# TextBox.Text += "string"; vs TextBox.AppendText("string");

Tags: c#, winforms, stringbuilder

what is the difference between these two methods?

Is one more efficient than the other?

I was thinking maybe the AppendText() uses a method similar to the StringBuilder, ie it uses its own cache instead of creating and appending a new string each time, is that true?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at it in a reflector, AppendText simply appends via calculating the end position then adding via .SelectedText

Comment: Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As it is clearly mentioned in [Remarks section of MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The AppendText method enables the user to append text to the contents of a text control without using text concatenation, which, can yield better performance when many concatenations are required.

Your question,

> what is the difference between these two methods?

We all know how `TextBox.Text += something;` will work i.e. creating and appending a new string each time but how `AppendText` works I could not find any code snippet whether internally it uses `StringBuilder` or something else.

> Is one more efficient than the other?

I think answer to above question will depend on the situation, **(Based on Test case observation)**

> if **`Multiline`** property is set to **`false`** then **Concatenation (+=)** yields better results but on other hand **`Multiline`** property is set to **`true`** then **`AppendText`** yields far better performance.

**EDIT** After reading the [comment from Rawling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632372/textbox-text-string-vs-textbox-appendtextstring/20632719#comment30886034_20632719) I made a custom win-form solution in which I had a simple `textbox` in which I appended a simple string `hello` **10000** times using a simple `for-loop`

```
    private void btnAppendText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtText.Text = string.Empty;
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            txtText.AppendText(s);
        }
        DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
        txtTime.Text = (endTime.Ticks - startTime.Ticks).ToString();
    }

    private void btnConcante_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtText.Text = string.Empty;
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            txtText.Text += s;
        }
        DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
        txtTime.Text = (endTime.Ticks - startTime.Ticks).ToString();
    }
```

**Output** were very surprising,
**TEST 1:  Multiline property is true**
I had to reduce the iteration to half i.e. 5000 for text concatenation as it was taking a very long time.

> `btnAppendText_Click` output on `txtTime` was **`37222129`** almost 3-4 seconds for 10000 iteration
> `btnConcante_Click` output on `txtTime` was **`14449906487`** more than 25 minutes for only 5000 iterations.

From the above result it is really clear that, `AppendText` is much faster and more efficient (when `Multiline` is `true`) than `Concatenation`

**TEST 2:  Multiline property is false**

> `btnConcante_Click` output on `txtTime` was **`39862280`** almost 3-4 seconds for 10000 iteration
> `btnAppendText_Click` output on `txtTime` was **`1043279672`** almost 2-3 minutes for 10000 iteration

From the above result it is really clear that, Concatenation is faster and more efficient (when `Multiline` is `false`) than `AppendText`

Comment: Surely this can be considered similar to the benefit you get from using StringBuilder compared to +=, when many concatenations are needed?

Comment: The MSDN documentation is actually rubbish. `AppendText` is not more efficient than concatenation. I ran a performance test and `.Text +=` is an orders of magnitude quicker than `.AppendText`.

Comment: @dbw - not true - we have reflector :) Microsoft code isn't protected from being looked upon (on purpose)

Comment: @Rawling **.Text +=** is not faster see my edited answer

Comment: @Rawling was there something else on your computer or in your test case, I am using Window Application on .net framework 4 client profile, can you provide some details about your test case....

Comment: @user2063755 Not sure about it because I do not know how `AppendText` is implemented by Microsoft as I can not find code for it

Comment: @dbw I've tried to replicate your test as closely as possible (switched to .NET 4 client profile, switched to using a class variable rather than a string literal, adding 5 characters rather than one, looping 10k rather than 1k times) and my `+=` loop still finishes in 3s while my `AppendText` runs for about 2 minutes. I guess the MSDN documentation is not total rubbish - it's correct to say it *can* yield better performance since you've witnessed it! - but I'd *love* to know why we're seeing such opposite results. As with all performance questions, it's up to OP to profile his real-world use!

Comment: can you guys let us know the outcome? I'm also interested.

Answer (score 0):

The AppendText has nothing to do with StringBuilder. The Text method actually seems simpler (an possibly more performant). See source code of those two methods for reference:

```
public void AppendText(string text)
{
    if (text.Length > 0)
    {
        int start;
        int length;
        this.GetSelectionStartAndLength(out start, out length);
        try
        {
            int endPosition = this.GetEndPosition();
            this.SelectInternal(endPosition, endPosition, endPosition);
            this.SelectedText = text;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (base.Width == 0 || base.Height == 0)
            {
                this.Select(start, length);
            }
        }
    }
}


public override string Text {
  get {
    return base.Text;
  }
  set {
    if (value != base.Text) {
      base.Text = value;
      if (base.IsHandleCreated) {
        base.SendMessage(185, 0, 0);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but it doesn't even appear to persist a selection properly :-/ E.g. I've put a `KeyDown` handler that calls `AppendText` when you hit Control, and it still clears any selection you've maide.

Comment: @Rawling - thanks for the update, I actually guessed what it does from source code (head compiler) rather than actually trying to see how it works in real life :) I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to `dbw` (and in case someone can find where I've made a mistake), here's my performance test:

```
private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Reset();
    textBox1.Text = "";
    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        textBox1.Text += s;
    }
    sw.Stop();
    var e1 = sw.Elapsed;

    sw.Reset();
    textBox1.Text = "";
    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText(s);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    var e2 = sw.Elapsed;
}
```

I see `e1` with about 3 seconds and `e2` with about 2 minutes.

Comment: I reduced the loop to `1000` in first case as it took more time, the output while debugging I got `TotalSeconds = 16.334709399999998` and with `AppendText` `10000` iterations `TotalSeconds = 3.7410611`

Comment: Please try the same code by making the property `Multiline` to `true`

Comment: @dbw Nice one. I get opposite results with `Multiline` on! Good of Microsoft to document this somewhere...

Comment: an I got the opposite result when `Multiline` was false